# General Care of a Dog's Pads?

Tags: dogs

Peanut and I returned from our afternoon long walk, and she's passed out on my lap. She is a 2 and a half year old medium standard female Dachshund. As she was sleeping, I checked her paws, nails, pads, etc. to see if she needed any nail trimming (she didn't.)

As I was doing this, I noticed her pads have a few, well, rough patches. Now normally her pads are smooth in one direction (back to front) and slightly rough, or grippy in the other (front to back) and I'm not really sure why that is, but that's normal.

Today, however, one of her pads, left front main (or center) pad, has a patch of roughness, that I can feel in any direction. Need I be concerned? If so, what would I do (other than a vet trip, which I will if needed, but would rather home remedy it)?

How should a dog's pads be cared for, generally speaking, or do we simply leave them alone?

Comment: Rough paws are fine.

Comment: Photo would be helpful.

Comment: @BasilBourque Unfortunately (or not, actually) I can't... it's all healed/better now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't be overly concerned, dogs feet are fairly tough however that being said be careful of hot pavement and salt (for removing ice).

If you feel like they are getting dry/cracked you can apply musher's dog paw wax. If you walk on hot pavement or salty roads, dog booties are beneficial (though not all dogs like them).

If your pup becomes sensitive to the area it could be a "corn", though I have never seen them on Dachshunds (see them all the time on greyhounds). No one knows why they get them, a lot of speculation though. They just need to be dug out by veterinary personnel.

Picture of corn, the white circle on inner digit. : [image]

Comment: Besides the “musher's dog paw wax”, a little "Bag Balm", gardener's balm with beeswax, lip wax/balm, or coconut oil may help with a dried-out or slightly cracked pad.